# how i can add autocomplete off to elementor search form input?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to disable previous search suggestions in my site.
I use Elementor search form.
I can edit it from the plugin editor but I can't find the file where I can add the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code into your theme function.php file it will add autocomplete='off' attribute**

```
class Elementor_Forms_Input_Classes {



    public function __construct() {
        // Add class attribute to form field render
        add_filter( 'elementor_pro/forms/render/item', [ $this, 'maybe_add_css_class' ], 10, 3 );

        add_action( 'elementor/element/form/section_form_fields/before_section_end', [ $this, 'add_css_class_field_control' ], 100, 2 );
    }
    public function add_css_class_field_control( $element, $args ) {
        $elementor = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
        $control_data = $elementor->controls_manager->get_control_from_stack( $element->get_name(), 'form_fields' );
    
        if ( is_wp_error( $control_data ) ) {
          return;
        }
    
      public function maybe_add_css_class( $field, $field_index, $form_widget ) {
            $form_widget->add_render_attribute( 'input' . $field_index, 'autocomplete', 'off' );
          $form_widget->add_render_attribute( 'select' . $field_index, 'autocomplete', 'off' );
        return $field;
      }
    }
    new Elementor_Forms_Input_Classes();
```

Answer (score -1):

to do that you will need to follow these steps:

1. Give your search form an id or class name (for example i will give my form a class name: **tho-auto-off**)
2. Insert an HTML code element, and put in this code:

   ```
   <script>
    jQuery(".tho-auto-off input").focus(function(){
       jQuery(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    });
   </script>
   ```
3. Save and enjoy.

**In case of this guide is not clearly enough for you - i have record a [guide video for this here](https://youtu.be/5ipXsBxLUXM).**